# Getting Invalid Key Store format error when running MUnit Tests in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, mule, mule-studio, munit

I am enabling SSL in my mulesoft application.
I have added a keyStore in my application in http request connector.
Everything works fine. Deployed to cloudhub by skipping Munits and tested. Everything works fine. Munit are running fine in local machine.
But when I run MUnit tests in jenkins. It throws below error.

> Caused by:
> org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException:Unable to
> initialise TLS configuration
>
> Caused by:org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.CreateException: Failed to
> load KeyStore:
> /mnt/jenkins/workspace/mule-jobs/application-prc-nonprod/target/munitworkingdir-5223661232046316/container/apps/application-prc/server-keystore-nonprod.jks
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

I have enabled this TLS for mulesoft system API and I am mocking this request connector. Not sure why it wants this jks file from jenkins location as shown in the error.

Any lead would be really helpful.

Http connection configuration

```
<http:request-config name="Mule_AWS_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="067166d7-313b-432a-b653-88617b728c5a" responseTimeout="${muleApi.aws.response.timeout}">
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="${muleApi.aws.host} " connectionIdleTimeout="${muleApi.aws.idletTimeout}">
            <reconnection >
                <reconnect frequency="${muleApi.aws.retryFrequency}" count="${muleApi.aws.reconnectionAttempts}" />
            </reconnection>
            <tls:context>
                <tls:trust-store insecure="true"/>
                <tls:key-store type="jks" path="${tls.keyStore.path}" keyPassword="${secure::tls.keyStore.keyPassword}" password="${secure::tls.keyStore.password}" />
            </tls:context>
        </http:request-connection>
    </http:request-config>
```

Http request

```
<http:request method="POST" doc:name="POST ZIP / aws system api call" doc:id="965033c6-4623-45cd-9326-920534684ace" config-ref="Mule_AWS_Request_configuration" path="${muleApi.aws.path}" responseTimeout="600000" requestStreamingMode="ALWAYS">
            <non-repeatable-stream />
                <http:headers><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "client_secret" : p('secure::muleApi.aws.client_secret'),
    "Content-Type" : "application/zip",
    "client_id" : p('secure::muleApi.aws.client_id')
}]]]></http:headers>
            <http:query-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "bucketName" : p('muleApi.aws.params.bucketName'),
    "key" : vars.key,
    "extractZipContent": vars.extractZipContent default "true",
    "extractContentType": vars.extractContentType default "csv"
}]]]></http:query-params>
            <http:response-validator>
                <http:success-status-code-validator values="200..499" />
            </http:response-validator>
        </http:request>
```

Location of keyStore.

path: src/main/resource/server-keystore-nonprod.jks

I am just mocking the request connector as shown below.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Mule Version is 4.4.0

MUnit version is 2.3.5

Providing the logs till i see this error below.

```
INFO  2022-12-07 09:27:52,417 [munit.01] org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer: Waiting for client connection 
INFO  2022-12-07 09:27:52,418 [munit.01] org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer: Client connection received from localhost - true
WARN  2022-12-07 09:27:52,859 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.config.internal.dsl.spring.ComponentConfigurationBuilder: Parameter ignore from extension munit has a defaultValue configured in the componentBuildingDefinition but not in the extensionModel.
INFO  2022-12-07 09:27:53,029 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.api.message.AbstractMuleMessageBuilderFactory: Loaded MuleMessageBuilderFactory implementation 'org.mule.runtime.core.internal.message.DefaultMessageBuilderFactory' from classloader 'java.net.URLClassLoader@3bbf841e'
WARN  2022-12-07 09:27:53,056 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.security.tls.TlsProperties: File tls-default.conf not found, using default configuration.
INFO  2022-12-07 09:27:53,057 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.api.tls.AbstractTlsContextFactoryBuilderFactory: Loaded TlsContextFactoryBuilderFactory implementation 'org.mule.runtime.module.tls.api.DefaultTlsContextFactoryBuilderFactory' from classloader 'java.net.URLClassLoader@3bbf841e'
WARN  2022-12-07 09:27:53,097 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.module.tls.internal.DefaultTlsContextFactory: TLS context  trust store set as insecure. No certificate validations will be performed, rendering connections vulnerable to attacks. Use at own risk.
INFO  2022-12-07 09:27:57,038 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising Bean: org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.ConfigurationProviderToolingAdapter-HTTP-requestConfig-implicit
INFO  2022-12-07 09:27:57,054 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting Bean: org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.ConfigurationProviderToolingAdapter-HTTP-requestConfig-implicit
INFO  2022-12-07 09:27:58,454 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising Bean: org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.DynamicConfigurationProvider-JSON_Logger_Config
INFO  2022-12-07 09:27:58,458 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising Bean: org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.ConfigurationProviderToolingAdapter-Mule_AWS_Request_configuration
org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Unable to initialise TLS configuration
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Unable to initialise TLS configuration
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.CreateException: Failed to load KeyStore: /mnt/jenkins/workspace/mule-jobs-nonprod/biz-prc-marketing-bulk-api-nonprod/target/munitworkingdir-5223661232046316/container/apps/biz-prc-marketing-bulk-api/server-keystore-nonprod.jks
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

Comment: It is hard to understand without actually having the MUnit code. Can you also add it? also add more logs where it is visible at what stage is the test throwing error.

Comment: Munit is bit simple. Fetching data from reddit ads ( mocking reddit api ) and then calling another aws mulesoft system api ( mocking this as well ).

This error comes before even starting to run munit test cases. Let me check if i can clean the logs and share it here.

Comment: Can you check if you have [enabled flow source](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/2.3/enable-flow-sources-concept) of the flow with the HTTP Listener

Comment: Added the logs till i get this error. Above logs start after the apps being deployed.

Comment: I havent enable the flow source. Will enabling this will effect loading the .jks files by jenkins server as shown in the error? Just curious.

Comment: By default, when running MUnits, the flow sources, like `http-listener` will not be enabled, but you can enable them with that option. I thought if your MUnit is trying to load the keystore for http listener, then it could have been enabled

Comment: I have added keyStore to the request connector, when calling another mulesoft api. But let me add the flow source and see if that helps. Thanks for the suggestion Harshank

Comment: No! it will not help, you should not enable it if you do not want to test by actually triggering the flow from a HTTP request of something. It was not clear that your request connector is using keystore too. Therefore I suggested it.

Comment: I understand. So we are calling system api using internal url for we enable ssl and using a keyStore in request connector, where i get this error.

Comment: You haven't provide enough details. Share the HTTP connector configuration, TLS configuration (if any), versions of Mule and MUnit, and HTTP request from the flow that you are unit testing.

Comment: And where is the keystre file located when you build the application?

Comment: Hi @aled , provided missing details. Let me know if need more information

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for configurations or code. For Mule use the XML text. Kindly add the HTTP connector configuration and the HTTP request operation. For the paths just textual path or a text directory listing.

Comment: Hi @aled, added the xml configuration as suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250292/discussion-between-aled-and-joono).